# JNLP and FileOutputStream

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp, fileoutputstream

I haven't done any program that utilizes Java Web Start. However, since I need to develop a program that I can automatically update remotely, I am thinking of delivering it via JNLP.

My question is, will it run given that the program uses FileOutputStream?

Before answering, I must indicate here that I cannot use an Open Dialog because I am outputting to a printer on a shared location (example: //computer/epsonlx300). Also, not very familiar with sandbox permissions, etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you electronically sign your jar, it will not be able to write anywhere outside the JWS sandbox (unless the user gives permission through an open dialog). This is mostly for security reasons, but makes developing a Java Web Start app fairly frustrating.

Unfortunately since you need to write to a location outside of the sandbox, you can't use JWS unless you sign it.

For future reference, there is a JNLP service called `PersistenceService` that will allow you to write to the sandbox. Think of it like writing cookies, except that it's for Java Web Start apps only.

Comment: Good thing I asked first before devoting some effort. Thanks

Comment: *" it will not be able to write anywhere outside the JWS sandbox (unless the user gives permission through an open dialog)."*  That is misleading.  A `FileOutputStream` is ***always*** outside the 'security sandbox'.  It does not matter where the location is.  The JNLP file save service OTOH, can be used by a sand-boxed app. and will produce the 'prompt' you are referring to.  If the app. is deployed as `all-permissions` then the user is not prompted when showing those save/open dialogs.  *"since you need to write to a location outside of the sandbox, you can't use JWS unless you sign it."* ..

Comment: ..  You can't deploy a ***sandboxed*** applet or JWS app. these days without digitally signing the code.